# Подсветка текста в Richedit

Tags: c++, winapi

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу проект на C++ и WinAPI. В проекте мне нужна такая фича: подсветка текста в `Richedit`. Основа реализации подсветки - функция `Highlight` в классе `CColoredRichTextBox`

```
class CColoredRichTextBox
{
public:
    CColoredRichTextBox(){}
    CColoredRichTextBox(HWND hWndOwner, int x, int y, int width, int height, int iMenuId);

    void Highlight(UINT uFirstVisibleChar, UINT uLastVisibleChar, COLORREF color);
    void HighlightClear();

    HWND hWnd;
};

void CColoredRichTextBox::Highlight(UINT uStartPos, UINT uEndPos, COLORREF color)
{
     //Нужно сделать цвет текста с uStartPos до uEndPos 
}
```

Каким образом можно это сделать (т. е. что мне нужно написать в тело функции `Highlight`)?

Answer (score 2):

А я бы сделал так, сохранить позицию, задать позицию разцветки, разкрасить, восстановить позицию:

```
void CColoredRichTextBox::Highlight(UINT uStartPos, UINT uEndPos, COLORREF color){
 CHARRANGE cr;
 CHARRANGE save;
 cr.cpMin=uStartPos;
 cr.cpMax=uEndPos;
 SendMessage(hWnd, EM_EXGETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&save);// запомнить
 SendMessage(hWnd, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&cr);  // новая позиция
 CHARFORMAT cf;
  cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
  cf.dwMask = CFM_COLOR; 
  cf.crTextColor = color; 
 SendMessage(hWnd, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cf);
 SendMessage(hWnd, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&save); // вернуть позицию
}
```

Ну и для разнообразия, подсветка SQL наброски (borland)

```
int colors [] = {0,0x606060, 0x202020, 0 , 0};

struct CheckPos{
  int pos;
  char loc[4]; /*st letter, end letter, state , is-updated*/  };
//
CheckPos checks[256];
CheckPos checks2[256];
int  checks_i;
//
void AddSpell(int pos, int style, char st, char end, char xor) {
  if ((checks_i>0)&&(checks[checks_i-1].pos==pos)) checks_i--;
  checks[checks_i].pos = pos;
  checks[checks_i].loc[0] = style;
  checks[checks_i].loc[1] = st;
  checks[checks_i].loc[2] = xor;
  checks[checks_i].loc[3] = (checks_i==0)?0 : ((pos - checks[checks_i-1].pos) & 255 );
  checks_i++;
  };
//
int scmp1(const void *c1, const void * c2 ) { return lstrcmpA((char*)c1,*(char**)c2);};
//===============================================================
void SpellCheck() { // Сама подсветка
  HANDLE Handle = edit1.Handle;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int xi = 0;
  char buf[256];
  char reserv_wrd[32];
  int rsw = 0;
  int comment_cnt = 0;
  int state = 0;
  char prev = 0;
  char xor = 0;
  int xstart = 0;
  int xend = 0;
  char st = 0;
  char c;
  int ppos[2];
  int npos[3];
  THWND::CHARFORMAT fmt ;
  checks_i = 0;
  fmt.dwEffects = 0;
  fmt.dwMask = /*CFM_COLOR*/0x40000001 /*CFM_BOLD*/;
  fmt.cbSize = sizeof(fmt);

  npos[0] = xi; /*from*/
  npos[1] = xi+254; /*to*/
  npos[2] = (int)&buf;
  //edit1.GetText(buf,i,i+254);
  ::SendMessageA(Handle,EM_GETTEXTRANGE,0,(DWORD)&npos);
  buf[255] = 0;
  AddSpell(0,0,buf[0],0,0);
  while (buf[0] != 0) {
  for (i=0; buf[i]!=0; i++) {
   c= buf[i];
   xor ^= c;
   if (st ==0) st = buf[i];
   if ((state == 0) || (state==1))
     if ((prev=='/')&&(buf[i]=='*')){ /* begin comment */
       xstart = xi + i;
       AddSpell(xstart-1,1,st,0,xor); /*Комментарий открыт*/
       state = 1;
       xor = 0; st = 0;
       prev = '*';
       i++; continue;
       };
   if (state == 1) { /*Коментарий*/
      if ((prev == '*')&&(buf[i]=='/')) {
         state = 0; /*end comment*/
         AddSpell(xi+i+1,  0,st,0,xor);/*Комментарий закрыт*/
         i++;
         xor = 0;   st = 0;
         }
      };
   if (rsw < 30) reserv_wrd[rsw++] = c | ((c > 'A')?32:0); /*в нижний регистр*/
   if (((c<'0')||(c>'9'))&& ((c<'A')||(c>'Z')) && ((c<'a')||(c>'z'))) {
      j=0;
      if (rsw !=0) rsw--;
      reserv_wrd[rsw] = 0;
      if ((rsw > 1)&&(rsw<30)) { /* Поиск зарезервированых слов */
         const char*  rsv1[] = {"as","and","begin","create", "from","function","index","insert", "into", "select","update","using","where"};
         if (bsearch(reserv_wrd, rsv1, sizeof(rsv1)/sizeof(rsv1[1]),sizeof(char*),scmp1)) j++;
         };
      if (j) { /*Если найдено*/
         AddSpell(xi+i-rsw,2,reserv_wrd[0],0,xor);
         xor = 0; st = 0;
         AddSpell(xi+i,0,buf[i],0,xor);
         };
      rsw = 0;
      };
   if (state!=1)
   if ((prev == '-') &&(buf[i]=='-')) { /*До конца строки*/
       }
     prev = buf[i];
     }
  xi += i;
  if (i != 254)  break;
  npos[0] = xi; /*from*/  /*Следующий кусок текста*/
  npos[1] = xi+254; /*to*/
  ::SendMessageA(Handle,EM_GETTEXTRANGE,0,(DWORD)&npos);
  }
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Отсеивание дублей, повторов в разукрашке
  CheckPos * ch_from, *ch_to;
  ch_from = checks;
  ch_to = checks2;
  int nomore_check = 0;
  int dest_cur = -1;
  for (i=0; i<checks_i; i++) {
     j = 0;
     __int64 cmp = *(__int64*)&ch_from[i];
     for (j=0;j<20;j++) {
        if ((dest_cur +  j ) >= 0 ) {
            if (ch_to[dest_cur +  j].pos == -1) break;
            if (*(__int64*)&ch_to[dest_cur +  j] ==cmp) {
               ch_from[i].loc[0] |= 64; /*Дубль найден*/
               dest_cur++;
               nomore_check = 0;
               break;
               };
            }
        }
     if (j==20) {
        if (nomore_check++ > 20) break;
        }
     };
  j = 0;   //---------------------------------------------------------
  ch_from[checks_i].pos = -1;  // Сам рендеринг
  for (i=0; i<=checks_i; i++) {
    // ch_from[i].loc[0] &= 63;
    if ((ch_from[i].loc[0] & 64 )
        &&(ch_from[i+1].loc[0] & 64 )
          ){
       ch_from[i].loc[0] &= 63; /*Снять отметку дубля и не выводить*/ } else { ch_from[i].loc[0] &= 63; // Снять отметку
       fmt.crTextColor = colors[ch_from[i].loc[0]];
       fmt.dwEffects = (ch_from[i].loc[0] == 2) ? 1 : 0; /*Жирное*/
       npos[0] = ch_from[i].pos;
       npos[1] = (ch_from[i+1].pos == -1) ? xi : (ch_from[i+1].pos + 1);
       //edit1.CharFormat(&fmt,1,  ,
       ::SendMessageA(Handle,  EM_EXGETSEL, 0, (DWORD)&ppos);
       ::SendMessageA(Handle,  EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (DWORD)&npos);
       ::SendMessageA(Handle,  EM_SETCHARFORMAT, 1, (DWORD)&fmt);
       ::SendMessageA(Handle,  EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (DWORD)&ppos);

       }
     j = ch_from[i].pos ;
     *(__int64*)&ch_to[i] = *(__int64*)&ch_from[i];
    }
  ch_to[i].pos = -1;
  //if (j < xi)    edit1.CharFormat(&fmt,
  };
```

Comment: А обновленной версии нет? :) P.S. И на GNU GCC собирается в Code::Block, только `xor` надо переименовать.

Answer (score 1):

```
void CColoredRichTextBox::Highlight(UINT uStartPos, UINT uEndPos, COLORREF color)
{
   CHARRANGE cr;
   cr.cpMin = uStartPos;
   cr.cpMax = uEndPos;
   SendMessage(hWnd, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&cr);
   CHARFORMAT cf;
   SendMessage(hWnd, EM_GETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cf);
   cf.cbSize = sizeof(cf);
   cf.dwMask = CFM_COLOR; 
   cf.crTextColor = color; 
   SendMessage(hWnd, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cf);
}
```

Comment: Не работает. И обработки WM_CREATE основного окна создаю CColoredRichTextBox и пробую подсветить часть текста: 
rtb1 = CColoredRichTextBox(hWnd, 280, 20, 330, 560, IDC_RTB_FIRST);
rtb1.Highlight(0, 2, RGB(255, 0, 0));
Но текст остается черным.
CColoredRichTextBox::CColoredRichTextBox(HWND hOwner, int x, int y, int w, int h, int i)
{
 LoadLibrary(L"Msftedit.dll");
 hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, MSFTEDIT_CLASS, TEXT("text"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, x, y, w, h, hOwner, (HMENU)i, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
}

Comment: EM_GETCHARFORMAT не нужен, нужно  EM_EXGETSEL - запомнить позицию,  EM_EXSETSEL ,  EM_SETCHARFORMAT,  и   EM_EXSETSEL-восстановить позицию