# RichTextBox Замена цвета определенных строк

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Вообщем бьюсь уже 2 дня с **RichTextBox**'ом, не могу осилить,у меня есть консольный сервер, с него идет переадресация на **RichTextBox** (**WPF**), так вот я не могу понять как мне сделать так, чтобы те **строки** попадающие в **RichTextBox** с содержимым (**Log, Error, Warning**) окрашивались в соответствующие цвета,а все остальное оставалось произвольным цветом, я не могу понять как такое сделать, будьте добры набросайте пример пожалуйста. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На с++ пример тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555843/17974 а для с# названия похожи, как-то примерно так.

Comment: Это плюсы я так не умею )

Comment: Посмотрите сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423654/10105

Comment: Я почти все смотрел здесь уже, это немного не то, и слишком для такой простой задумки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам простой пример.

XAML:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="RTB" Background="Black" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RTB.Document.Blocks.Clear();
        Work();
    }

    async void Work()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        AddWithColor("First", Colors.White);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        AddWithColor("Second", Colors.Green);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        AddWithColor("Third", Colors.Red);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        AddWithColor("Fourth", Colors.Yellow);
    }

    void AddWithColor(string s, Color color)
    {
        var text = new Run(s) { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color) };
        var p = new Paragraph(text) { Margin = new Thickness(0, 2, 0, 2) };
        RTB.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: лог красиви палушился ошень]

Подобрать логику выбора цвета в зависимости от содержимого строки, надеюсь, сможете сами.

Comment: Что-то видимо надежда меня подвела... Вот пишу значит: `string s = "First message...\nJust Second...\nThird person...\nFourth fantastic...."; if (s.Contains("First"))
            {
                AddWithColor(s, Colors.White);
            }
            else if (s.Contains("Second"))
            {
                AddWithColor(s, Colors.Green);
            }
            else if (s.Contains("Third"))
            {
                AddWithColor(s, Colors.Red);
            }` Но чего то не хочет работать

Comment: @Malcolm: Не-не, никаких `\n`. Разбейте на 4 строки, и скармливайте их по одной, каждую со своим цветом.

Comment: Ну так а как, если мне данные приходят в таком вот формате

Comment: К тому же получается у меня постоянно идет практически непрерывный поток данных.

Comment: @Malcolm: Ну так разбейте по `\n`, в чём проблема?

Comment: Ну так выше комментарием я и разбил, только работать не хочет

Comment: @Malcolm: Странно, а вы конкретно мой код пробовали?

Comment: Ну пробовал, в таком виде, работает а когда пытаешься отловить нужное, красит только в первый попавшийся цвет

Comment: @Malcolm: Ну отлично, значит, проблема не в выводе в RichTextBox, а в другом коде, который определяет нужные цвета. Это уже не имеет отношения к вопросу.

Comment: А можете показать как правильно отлавливать цвета в вашем коде?

Comment: @Malcolm: Например, так: http://pastebin.com/98Wkptdx

Comment: А, ну так получается вы разделяете строки по переносу, ну а у меня я не уверен что в конце строки будет вообще какой-либо символ, по которому можно разделять, поэтому это не сработает.

Comment: @Malcolm: Ну, у вас же как-то всё равно нужно разделять строки? Вы ж должны понимать, какой кусок красить жёлтым, а какой зелёным? Без этого задача не имеет решения.

Comment: Все верно я зашел в тупик, слушайте а вот у меня такое тут, получается в строку попадает построчно весь текст вот так:  `while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string s = reader.ReadLine();` или я чего то не понимаю? В этой функции получается строки уже построчно отделены? нет?

Comment: @Malcolm: Эта функция делит строки по `\n` или `\r\n`, что найдёт. Лучше по идее читать так: `string s; while ((s = reader.ReadLine()) != null) { ... }`. НО! Вы не должны делать это в UI-потоке! Потому что блокировать UI-поток нельзя. Вы должны делать это в фоновом потоке, и доставлять строки в UI-поток через InvokeAsync или что-то такое.