# Как правильно реализовать подсветку кода?

Tags: .net, регулярные-выражения, алгоритм, wpf, компилятор

Хочу написать **минимально функционирующий** редактор кода **с подсветкой** для нескольких языков (например, html, css). Основная фича редактора - именно подсветка. Своя реализация. Понимаю, что с нуля такое не пишется, но мне это нужно чисто в учебных целях, для курсового проекта. Писать буду на .NET WPF но важно не это.
Главный вопрос: как делать подсветку? Как правильно именно на концептуальном уровне решать такую задачу?

Первое, что приходит в голову - с помощью регулярок вытаскивать из исходника ключевые слова языка и оборачивать их в цветастые элементы. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что нормальные люди так не делают. Вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 вообще говорят, что регулярками ничего более-менее сложного не распарсишь.

Подозреваю, что нужно копать в сторону слов "лексемы", "токены", "AST" и читать монструозную книгу http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3829076/
Если я прав, то укажите хотя бы, какие главы читать или ключевые слова, а то полностью прочесть такую книгу за одну жизнь как-то не очень реально.

В общем, а какую сторону мне копать c этой подсветкой?

Comment: Пример на с++ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430827/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-richedit  на с# сложно переписать

Comment: Вам нужно определится всётаки что будет 1. базой подсветки (html/rtf/другое/самописная) и 2. что будет рендерить (WebBrowser/Richedit/другое/самописный). И от этого уже отталкиваться.

Comment: Вам не нужны собственно компиляторы, нужен только синтаксический разбор - это намного проще. Есть гораздо более простые описания принципов и алгоритмов синтаксического разбора - насколько мне помнится, у Вирта в его канонических "Алгоритмах+структурах" этому отдельная глава посвящена и даже текст простенького компилятора приведен (на паскале, естественно). Вирт очень легко читается - уровень - школьный, всю книжку за пару дней можно проштудировать. Ну и погуглить можно. Есть методы почти тупомеханического преобразования формального описания языка в алгоритм его разбора.

Comment: Почитайте литературу по теории языков программирования