# Qt C++ textEdit менять цвет каждой строки

Tags: c++, qt

Как в `QTextEdit` сделать свой цвет для каждой строки? То есть не всего виджета, а конкретно для строки. К примеру, хочу зеленый цвет. Делаю так:

```
ui->textEdit->SetStyleSheet("Тут задаем цвет");
```

... но цвет меняется для всего виджета сразу и всех строк в нем. А мне нужно, чтобы только `ui->textEdit->append("Строка")` была зеленой, а все, что после нее, - в стандартном черном цвете.

Comment: Разноцветный текст можно делать 1.RichEdit (проще всего). 2. Ставите свойство "OwnerDraw" = true и отрисовуете через событие OnPaint "вручную" как вам нравится.

Comment: Как покрасить текст RichEdit - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430827/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-richedit/555843#555843), а from to можно вычислить по длинне строк.

Comment: а если вместо тра та та переменную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
QTextEdit txt_edit;

QTextCharFormat fmt = txt_edit.currentCharFormat();
fmt.setForeground(QBrush(Qt::red));

txt_edit.setCurrentCharFormat(fmat);
txt_edit.append("tra-ta-ta");

fmt = txt_edit.currentCharFormat();
fmt.clearForeground();
txt_edit.setCurrentCharFormat(fmat);
```

Можно иначе:

```
QTextEdit txt_edit;

txt_edit.insertHtml("<div><font color=\"red\">tra-ta-ta</font></div>");
```