# Настройка RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, richtextbox

Как известно, этот контрол ведет себя совсем не так, как обычный TextBox, особенно напрягают возможность вставки изображений посреди текста, с которыми не совсем понятно как работать, а также сохранение стилей исходного текста, опять же, при вставке. А хочется же всего-лишь взять его минимум, чтобы создать подсветку синтаксиса. Собственно, как бороться с таким поведением? Мне в голову приходит только перегрузка WndProc с последующими обработками некоторых нежалательных сообщений. Пока выходит не очень. Может, кто-то уже сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Взять готовый контрол с подсветкой синтаксиса?

Comment: Писать велосипеды полезно хотя бы потому, что я буду понимать, как это устроенно. Можно же много разных готовых систем в проект добавить ,но если оно начнет "сыпаться", я ничего не смогу сделать.

Comment: @Uranus, раз вы задаете такой вопрос `КАК`, значит вы не знаете как это написать, следовательно, раз есть готовое решение, которое можно взять и разобраться, как устроено, разве нет?

Comment: просто на самом деле `RichTextBox` хранит содержимое в формате [RTF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf(v=vs.110).aspx); незачем *бороться* с тем, что предназначено для использования.

Comment: Если брать исходники, то да, это можно будет считать ответом на мой вопрос.

Comment: Меня интересует только свойство SelectedColor не более, неужели проще переписать TextBox?

Comment: Обычный WINAPI контрол RichEdit32 без "дополнительной инициализации" - не поддерживает вставку картинок.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать более низкую версию https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873(v=vs.85).aspx, проверьте отсутствие вызова EM_SETOLECALLBACK, попробуйте скинуть EM_SETOLECALLBACK в null.

Comment: Вариант подсветки с++ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555843/17974

Comment: Если готовые решения-библиотеки не устраивают ! зачем тогда использовать `RichTextBox` ? напишите свой контрол с нуля

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, так и надо: тот функционал, который позволяет отключить сам этот элемент управления, надо отключить при его создании (путем соответствующей настройки его свойств).
А тот базовый функционал, который отключить через свойства невозможно, отключить через сабклассирование / суперклассирование элемента управления, организовав фильтрацию его сообщений, подавляя те, которые не нужны (например, отправлять в родительский класс код возврата, что сообщение уже обработано, но при этом ничего не делать либо игнорировать эти сообщения - разные сообщения требуют своего способа подавления).